# center navigation on top of div

Tags: css, center, nav

i'm trying to center the navigation tabs on top of a div. basically, I want the navigation centered on top of the div with a 2px stage in between each tab. The nav tabs now don't seem to sit centered on the .row.

any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

```
.row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#top-menu{
   font-family: "LeagueGothicRegular",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:240px;
  }

#top-menu li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 17px;
    text-align: center;
  }

#top-menu a{
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.97em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 18px;
  text-decoration: none
}

#top-menu a:hover,
#top-menu .active a{
  color: #fff;
  background: #E80B44;
  }
#top-menu a:hover .nav-arrow{
  border-top-color: {{settings.nav_hover_colour}};
  }

#top-menu ul .first ul{
  left: 0;
  }

#top-menu ul ul li{
        color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent;
  }

#top-menu ul ul {
  font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent;
  }

#top-menu > ul > li {
       font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: Please include code in your post. Not just a link.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: of course.. thanks.. I'm a relative newbie.. thought a visual reference would help..

Comment: .row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#top-menu{
   font-family: "LeagueGothicRegular",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
   margin-top:240px;
  }

Comment: #top-menu li{display: block;float: left;line-height: 1;margin: 0 17px;text-align: center;
  }

#top-menu a{font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif;background-color: #fff;border-top-left-radius: 5px;border-top-right-radius: 5px;color: #000000; display: inline-block;font-size: 1.97em;line-height: 1;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);padding: 2px 18px; text-decoration: none
}


#top-menu ul .first ul{left: 0;}

Comment: #top-menu ul ul li{color: #000000; display: inline-block;font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent;}

#top-menu ul ul {font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif; display: inline-block; border: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent;
  }

#top-menu > ul > li {font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif;}

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `display: block;` of `#top-menu li` to `display: inline-block;` and remove `float: left;`
2. Add `text-align:center;` to `#top-menu ul`

When this is done, your navigation will be centered when you decrease the margins.

Comment: oh, so close! nearly there.. just not totally centered.. any idea what I'm not doing right? THANKS SO MUCH THOUGH!

Comment: Try adding padding: 0; to the `#top-menu ul`. I think there was some padding on the left side (not sure, since you removed the link :) ).